# JSONobject: call method 'substr' of null

Tags: substr, json

Please suggest me

```
 var rest = JSONobject[i]["descrizione"];
 var descr = rest.substr(0,15);
```

ERROR: Cannot call method 'substr' of null

but "var rest" is NOT empty.

That's code completed:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_info_campotrincerato.php",
    success: function (result) {
        var JSONobject = JSON.parse(result);
        var jnCount = JSONobject.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < jnCount; i++) {

            var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(JSONobject[i]["lat"], JSONobject[i]["lng"]),{ icon: myIcon1 });
            var rest = JSONobject[i]["descrizione"];
            var descr = rest.substr(0,15);

            var list = "<dl>"
                    + "<dt><b>ID:</b> " + JSONobject[i]["id"] + "</dt>"

                    + "<dt>" + descr + "</dt>"
                    + "<a href='?id=" + JSONobject[i]["id"] + "'>...go</a>";



            marker.bindPopup(list);             
                marker.on('dblclick', function(e){
                    marker.openPopup();
                    });
```

Comment: _“but "var rest" is NOT empty”_ – the JS engine seems to have a different opinion on that. So, how did you _validate_ this …?

Comment: Hi,because if I use just only

    var rest = JSONobject[i]["descrizione"];
 

in:

 [...]

            var list = "<dl>"
                    + "<dt><b>ID:</b> " + JSONobject[i]["id"] + "</dt>"

                    + "<dt>" + rest+ "</dt>"
                    + "<a href='?id=" + JSONobject[i]["id"] + "'>...go</a>";


[...]

I can see "var rest" content, without error.

Comment: Add a `console.log(rest)` before the substr line in your code, and see what dbug output you get in the console for each loop iteration.

Comment: Hi, I use firebug.

Console:

TypeError: rest is null
var descr_short = rest.substr(0,15);

Please have a look to that links:

http://www.nexusmultimedia.it/index2_campotrincerato.php (without error)
http://www.nexusmultimedia.it/index_campotrincerato.php (with error)

Comment: Debugging that script (using Firebug’s debugger) clearly shows that `rest` __is__ null at some point, because for the first object in `JSONobject`, the `descrizione` __is__ null.